# SQL and C# retrieving a single record from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a webpage built with a dropdown that has a list of books.  These books are stored on the sql sever. Using the MVC and aspx pages i am trying to figure out how to retrieve information about about a book such that when the user selects a book it passes the price of the book. I am new to sql sever and var statements.

1. I am able to retrieve the books name from the webpage and send it to my controller
2. In my model i am trying to get that data here is my thought.  I want to get the price and store into a string. But the only way i have seen to pull information is using the var statement.

such that

```
var price = from p in BooksDB.Price
 where p.Book_Name==bookName
    select new {p.Book_Price}
```

but how do i get that value and store it into a string based on the Books_Name that I have retrieved from the dropdown box

by the way my table looks like this

```
Id_Num   Book_Name    Book_Price
  1       Pro C#       29.99
  2       Beg C++      10.99
```

Comment: If you have access to it when you're running your query I'd recommend using your Id_Num field (I'm assuming it's unique) rather than the bookname.  If you have a unique key on the id then it will be much faster and also eliminates the possibility of getting multiple rows back due to duplicate book titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a terminology correction.

`var` is just a keyword the compiler lets you use to subsitute for the type. During compiletime, the compiler will figure out what the type is based on usage.

```
var myString = "hihihi";
string myString = "hihihi";
```

The `var` statement has nothing to do with accessing a database, although it was added to make using LINQ easier on us lazy developers.

Instead what you are doing is creating a `LINQ to SQL` query. I've modified it slightly (you don't need to create an anonymous object). After you create the statement, you need to execute it by calling "ToList(), First(), or FirstOrDefault() etc"

LINQ typically employs lazy or deferred evaluation for queries, and isn't executed until you trigger execution.

```
var price = from p in BooksDB.Price
            where p.Book_Name==bookName
            select p.Book_Price;

//assuming Book_Price is stored as a string datatype.
string bookPrice = price.FirstOrDefault();
//otherwise
string bookPrice = (price.FirstOrDefault() ?? "").ToString();

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bookPrice))
{
    //do something with the string.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly something like below should work.

```
var record = BooksDB.Price.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Book_Name == bookName);
```

If `record` is not `null` at this point then `record.Book_Price` should contain the data you are looking for (not accounting for ambiguity in the database.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `select new {p.Book_Price}`, use something like `select p.Book_Price`. You could add `.ToString()` to the end to force it to come out as a String rather than the data type from the table.

You'll also want to wrap the entire LINQ statement in () and append `.FirstOrDefault()` to get just one value. The "OrDefault" part protects you from an exception when the result set us empty.